# PHP PEAR Godaddy server SMTP connection refused

Tags: php

I'm facing the below exception

> Failed to connect to smtpout.asia.secureserver.net:465 [SMTP: Invalid
>   response code received from server (code: -1, response: )]

I'm using `PHP 7.1.12-3+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)` and `PEAR Version: 1.10.5`.

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
try {
    require_once "Mail.php"; 
    $from = "support@domain.com";
    $to = "user@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Testing email please ignore";
    $message = "Just testing";
    $host = "smtpout.asia.secureserver.net";
    $port = 465;
    $username = "support@domain.com";
    $password = "password";
    $headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);
    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
            echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
    } else {
            echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
?>
```

Do I need to change any settings in Godaddy?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using their(Godaddy) email address,SMTP_SERVER should be localhost.
If you are using google server to send the emails change SMTP_SERVER accordingly.

hope this helps

```
$host: "localhost" //use godaddy server as smtp
```